# How to get multiple images from Meta Graph API for posts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

For carousel posts, we can get all the data in the child attachments field in the posts endpoint, we know that. We want to get multiple images from a post that is not a carousel. We can only get the first image for it so far in the full_picture endpoint. The endpoint we are using for this is:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/
```

The API call is as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/<post_id>/?fields=id,actions,admin_creator,application,backdated_time,child_attachments,created_time,from,full_picture,message,message_tags,place,properties,shares,status_type,permalink_url,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(1).as(love),reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(like),comments.summary(1).as(comments)&access_token=<access_token>
```

All data that we want to get programmatically is from public pages.

Comment: You should find those under `attachments`.